# Git: Different Client/Server Files

Tags: git, github

Basically I have a project that will have some files that only be useful on client nodes (for example Jupyter notebooks) and some files that are only useful on a separate server node (for example cron-based scraping).  I'm not sure if or how I could have a single repository on GitHub store all of that information considering I'd prefer to avoid having to keep up-to-date copies of all files in each location.

The answers on this thread ([Git branch structure for Client & Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5012015/git-branch-structure-for-client-server)) come very, very close.  I'm thinking the subdirectory option mentioned by Matt E. may be exactly what I'm looking for.

If I have something like:

```
Project

-> Server
---> Scraping

-> Client
---> Jupyter notebooks
```

The basic goal is to be able to push updates from my local laptop to the "Client" directory and from a remote machine to the "Server" directory without requiring that my client have locally stored files for the "Server" directory and vice-versa.

Comment: This is kind of a question of best practices - it depends.  I think in general you'd want to maintain multiple Git repositories for "separation of concerns" reasons.  Maybe one repository for server-related stuff and another for client-related stuff.

Comment: @alex I think you bring up a really good point.  I guess part of the trick here is that it's not _just_ a client/server distinction.  I also find it much easier to write documentation on my laptop as opposed to the server machine.  And having documentation for a program and the program itself in different repos just seems... wrong.  But it may just be the case that I need to accept that particular documentation challenge and get used to using TeX/markdown for that particular need.